# Using Spatialite in Android

Tags: postgis, spatialite

I want to develop an Android app with offline routing. I want to use Spatialite as the database in the client side. I am confused after reading their web. Since it is running on the Android side(cell phone), why the installation requirs to install many dependent softwares. Are they used for compilation only?  Can it be running on the android side?

Comment: Review this, I have a custom implementation for android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366380/can-i-use-room-persistence-for-a-different-type-of-database/61789920#61789920

Answer (score 0):

You can use spatialite on android!

You can see the official manual here:
https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=spatialite-android-tutorial

But also compare to this geopaparazzi project also utilizing spatialite:https://github.com/geopaparazzi/geopaparazzi/tree/master/geopaparazzispatialitelibrary

You should use the native spatialite libraries (libjsqlite.so) and the basic API classes, in the jsqlite package in the geopaparazzi project.