# Can I use Room Persistence for a different type of Database?

Tags: android, sqlite, geospatial, android-room, android-architecture

I know that room is an abstraction layer over SQLite, I just want to know if I can use it for a different type of Database. I want to use Room to a special version of SQLite with geospatial support, is it possible? I really can't find an answer about this one.

[Android Spatialite](https://github.com/sevar83/android-spatialite)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you are willing to write the bridge code for it.

One of the methods that you can call on a `RoomDatabase.Builder` [is `openHelperFactory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder.html#openHelperFactory(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory)). This takes an instance of `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory`, and this is what Room uses for interacting with the underlying database implementation. By default, Room uses  `FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory`, but via `openHelperFactory()` you can provide your own.

This, in turn, will require you to implement other interfaces on other classes, such as `SupportSQLiteDatabase`. This is basically a wrapper, with an API that somewhat resembles the framework API. You translate those calls to the SQLite implementation that you wish to use.

I did this for SQLCipher for Android, in the form of [the SafeRoom library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-saferoom). Right now, my implementation is a bit clunky, due to some limitations in SQLCipher for Android that hopefully will be lifted soon. You would create the same sort of classes for your particular SQLite implementation. Then, plug your `SupportSQLiteHelper.Factory` into your `RoomDatabase.Builder`, and now Room will talk to your database implementation.

Note that you cannot actually extend Room itself. For example, you cannot invent new Room annotations that know about geospatial stuff. And the Room compiler may have issues with your geospatial SQL, if that SQL breaks what Room is expecting (e.g., new keywords). It seems like what they added are "just" a lot of functions, so hopefully Room will behave OK.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I thought Room Persistence is only for SQLite.

Comment: @jzarsuelo Did you manage to implement Room-Spatialite bridge? If yes, please share!

Comment: Do you know if Room reuses the `openHelperFactory`? If so, then shouldn't we use sqlcipher's `SupportFactory()` with `clearPassphrase=false`?

Comment: @Mark: "Do you know if Room reuses the openHelperFactory?" -- I do not believe that the behavior is specified. "shouldn't we use sqlcipher's SupportFactory() with clearPassphrase=false?" -- um, well, this answer pre-dates what you are referring to. We specifically added `clearPassphrase` to allow developers to control the passphrase-clearing behavior. Some developers may prefer to clear the passphrase and wait to see if they encounter strange behavior from Room. Clearing the passphrase is better from a security standpoint.

Comment: Thanks Mark. It's just that the default (i.e. when using the single passphrase arg constructor) for `clearPassphrase` is `true` so if there are issues with the factory being reused, then that could cause some unexpected surprises.

Comment: @Mark: On the whole, SQLCipher for Android tends towards greater security as the default. And in this case, I have not heard of any problems, though I am not involved the day-to-day work of SQLCipher.

Answer (score 1):

You could use my current implementation of spatialite for Android room:

https://github.com/anboralabs/spatia-room

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm currently scouting for a Spatialite library for Android I could use in a project. Sevar83's library appears to be out-of-date, seeing as it hasn't been updated in almost 2 years. Will check out yours.

Comment: @znovotny let me know if was useful for you.

Comment: Darwin, have you used Spatia-Room with a real SpatiaLite database? I'm having a hard time using my database that has a table where the `geom` column has type `MULTIPOLYGON`. I am using the DAO approach, but I'm getting a runtime error because of a discrepancy between the expected and the found table structure. I might post a separate question for it on SO.

Comment: @znovotny please create the issue or publish a project and let me help you with the issue, I have used my library for some side projects. and works good.