# How to build android app with spatiallite in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, spatialite

I'm new in spatialite database in Android. I try to create an app that use spatialite for save and query spatial data. I tried several way, such as https://github.com/sevar83/android-spatialite, https://github.com/geopaparazzi/geopaparazzi/ and https://github.com/kristina-hager/HelloToSpatialite. But I couldn't. Is there any way to help me? How can I create such app? Thanks

Comment: Tutorial: https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=spatialite-android-tutorial

Comment: I created an android library for room and spatialite. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61789920/11014375